# Scikit-learn: preprocessing.scale() vs preprocessing.StandardScalar()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scale

I understand that scaling means centering the mean(mean=0) and making unit variance(variance=1).

But, What is the difference between `preprocessing.scale(x)`and `preprocessing.StandardScalar()` in scikit-learn?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Those are doing exactly the same, but:

- `preprocessing.scale(x)` is just a function, which transforms some data
- `preprocessing.StandardScaler()` is a class supporting the *Transformer API*

I would always use the latter, even if i would not need `inverse_transform` and co. supported by `StandardScaler()`.

Excerpt from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling):

> The function scale provides a quick and easy way to perform this operation on a single array-like dataset
>
> The preprocessing module further provides a utility class StandardScaler that implements the Transformer API to compute the mean and standard deviation on a training set so as to be able to later reapply the same transformation on the testing set. This class is hence suitable for use in the early steps of a sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that scale will transform data in min-max range of the data, while standardscaler will transform data in range of [-1, 1].

Comment: Please have a look at the already accepted answer. It's a nice explaination.

Comment: Wrong. They are doing exactly the same!