# Is StandardScaler() or scale in sklearn for scaling data better for supervised machine learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have to scale some data before I can analyze the data and extrapolate trends and results. There are two ways under sklearn to scale data, using StandardScaler() or just scale.

Which of the two procedures is a more appropriate preprocessing step for supervised machine learning and why?

Comment: What do you mean by "just scale"?

Comment: My apologies for not clarifying. Sklearn has a preprocessing.scale(X) method, where X is the data that needs to be scaled. Sklearn also has a preprocessing.StandardScaler() method that does the same thing, or so I thought but it doesn't? One is supposed to be better for supervised machine learning.

Comment: Hey, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257627/scikit-learn-preprocessing-scale-vs-preprocessing-standardscalar

Comment: In terms of the result, there is no difference; it's just that you can use `StandardScaler` in a `Pipeline`.

Comment: My main question here is asking which one is preferable for supervised machine learning. The other answer only explains what they are.

Comment: Well everything is said: they are the same. Thus there is no difference for Supervised ML.... there is only a difference in the code flow as they are not the same object. One is not better than the other.